# NancyFX : Deserialize JSON

Tags: .net, json, rest, nancy

The documentation suggests the NancyFx helps me out WRT deserialization of json request body, but I'm not sure how.  See test below to demonstrate:

```
[TestFixture]
public class ScratchNancy
{
    [Test]
    public void RootTest()
    {
        var result = new Browser(new DefaultNancyBootstrapper()).Post(
            "/",
            with =>
                {
                    with.HttpRequest();
                    with.JsonBody(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new DTO {Name = "Dto", Value = 9}));
                });

        Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, result.StatusCode);
    }

    public class RootModule : NancyModule
    {
        public RootModule()
        {
            Post["/"] = Root;
        }

        private Response Root(dynamic o)
        {
            DTO dto = null;//how do I get the dto from the body of the request without reading the stream and deserializing myself?

            return HttpStatusCode.OK;
        }
    }

    public class DTO
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Model-binding](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Model-binding)

```
var f = this.Bind<Foo>();
```

EDIT (to put above into context for the benefit of other readers of this question)

```
public class RootModule : NancyModule
{
    public RootModule()
    {
        Post["/"] = Root;
    }

    private Response Root(dynamic o)
    {
        DTO dto = this.Bind<DTO>(); //Bind is an extension method defined in Nancy.ModelBinding

        return HttpStatusCode.OK;
    }
}
```

Comment: Got it, thanks, simple and elegant. I'm falling in love with Nancy.

Comment: Is there any prerequisite for o to be serialized? I passing a valid JSON string but my dynamic object has no keys or values.