# Cannot get body of POST from Nancy REST server embedded in Unity game

Tags: c#, mono, unity-game-engine, nancy

I'm trying to set up a route for a Nancy POST, where I wish to submit an object in Json format, and use this to trigger an event in the Unity runtime - what I thought should be fairly standard stuff.

I thought that by following the example in [NancyFX : Deserialize JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10723044/nancyfx-deserialize-json) I would be able to bind the body of the request to an object and then use that elsewhere, however I am actually getting this rather mysterious error:

```
Error CS1061: Type 'server.RESTServer' does not contain a definition for 'Bind' and no extension method 'Bind' of type 'server.RESTServer' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS1061) (server)
```

This is the relevent section from the offending source:

```
using Nancy;

namespace server
{
    public class RESTServer : Nancy.NancyModule, RESTInterface
    {
        public class LevelInfo
        {
            public string index;
        }
        public RESTServer ()
        {
            Delete ["/current/level"] = _ => 
            {
                UnloadLevel();
                return HttpStatusCode.OK;
            };
            Get ["/current/level"] = _ => Level;
            Post ["/current/level"] = _ => 
            {
                LevelInfo body = this.Bind<LevelInfo>(); //This is the offending line
                // snip rest of implementation
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My Mono/Monodevelop version info is [on pastebin here](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=vZLptqjv), and the Assembly Browser shows [this, also linked on pastebin,](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=NF45jL1Y) for Nancy.

I don't generally do much .net development so I'm sure it's something really simple, but I've already lost an afternoon trying to resolve this issue... Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Based on a comment in that linked example, you need to add `using Nancy.ModelBinding;` to the top of your code file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Bind<>` is extension method in `Nancy.ModelBinding` namespace.

You need `using Nancy.ModelBinding;`

Comment: D'oh I can't believe it could be so simple